Run script as part of systemd (with PID 1)
I have a piece of data that is shared across (v)fork, exec and clone. I want this data to be available across all processes. Therefore, I want to initialize this data inside systemd (since every other process as launched by it). How can I achieve that? How can I run a script as a part of systemd?
I've tried creating systemd servicies, but they aren't run under PID 1

Generally, you cannot. Systemd doesn't have such a feature (and neither does any other commonly used init that I know of… well, other than svchost.exe).
Other than patching systemd itself, it might be possible to do this by replacing systemd-init with your own initialization program that establishes the data and execs (without fork) the real systemd (an easy way to implement that is by modifying the initramfs since it's what actually starts as PID 1 and exec's the main init), or by using some ld.so configuration (maybe LD_PRELOAD) to forcefully link your own .so containing the setup code into the init process.
The question is whether it's actually a good idea to do so. If the data needs to be made available to every process, that implies it is not security-sensitive – and there are already multiple ways to publish such data that don't require weird hacks; namely:

Environment variables (e.g. systemctl set-environment);
Files (e.g. in the /run in-memory filesystem).

If this is related to your earlier questions about e4fscrypt, then likewise there are better ways to implement file unlocking, such as a file-based LUKS volume (i.e. cryptsetup on a loop device) – instead of using fscrypt, have the "unlocker" service call cryptsetup and mount the volume under /run/secure or something similar, and the files will become available to all services without needing to deal with keyrings.

First of all, huge thank you for such a detailed answer. Yes, this is indeed related to my earlier questions about e4fscrypt. Unfortunately, LUKS is exactly what I am trying to migrate from to file-based encryption because of <implementation_reasons>. Android OS has exactly what I want, but I can't figure out how do they share the kernel keyring key between all processes (and, most importantly, systemd services) that need it.

Maybe they don't? From what I remember, later fscrypt revisions do not rely on persistent access to keyrings anymore. Android might well have custom patches for it, though. Or, since they're in position to run any kind of code from their own init, they might have set it up so that all services join the same session keyring...

The more I read about it there more it seems to me than they have there own key management system instead of kernel keyring. And then they configure ecryptfs to use it instead of kernel keyring.

"since they're in position to run any kind of code from their own init". What do you mean? Do they not use systemd as an init system?

As far as I know, no, they don't (unless that changed recently, but it feels like there would be too much of an impedance mismatch with trying to integrate systemd into Android). But the point was that they're essentially building a whole OS, not just a distribution of existing code – e.g. they have a lot of custom daemons (and I would be entirely unsurprised if they also had their own init system as well) and they can freely patch and customize things.
